# Unable to access website on Safari (iOS)

Tags: ios, iis, safari, reverse-proxy, arr

I have a website that is hosted in apache web server under ubuntu. Now i setup a reverse proxy (ARR) in IIS  (windows server 2016) to point the subdirectory (/daily) to the website that is hosted in apache web server - ubuntu. When i try to access the website via safari on iOS, the website is not loading (The loading bar appears on the top-left corner; The loading bar disappears (almost immediately); I am back on the page I was before - The page was not reload, it is as if I did nothing...) however when i try to access it in chrome (laptop, android, pc), firefox, internet explorer and other non-ios browser, i can load the website successfully.This is the twist: when i try to access the website in ios safari using http (not secure), the page was loaded successfully.

I have tried another setup:
Instead of using apache web server for the reverse proxy website, i tried to use different server but this time its hosted in IIS, windows server 2016 and setup the same thing (same SSL certificate, same content). When i try to access this in safari ios (https & http), the page was loaded successfully.

I am guessing that there is an issue in reverse proxy that points to the apache web server when accessing via https in safari ios. It's really weird and i don't know what is really the issue here because when i try to access a normal website that is hosted in IIS along with the reverse proxy, i can access them successfully.

I hope you guys can help me in this issue.

This is the website url: https://www.investagrams.com/daily/ (you can also test them --- try to access in ios safari it would fail, and other browser --- all successful).

Answer (score 2):

I did some research and this happens because iOS 11 is improperly negotiating a HTTP/2 TLS connection and the connection fails. Microsoft has a fully supported workaround, which disables HTTP/2 TLS connections.
More information about the issue can be read here: https://www.essential.exchange/2017/09/18/ios-11-about-to-release-things-to-be-aware-of/

### Workaround

Disable HTTP/2 until its fixed by Apple.

To enable or disable HTTP/2, follow these steps:

1. Start regedit (Registry Editor).
2. Move to this subkey:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters

3. Set **DWORD** type value **EnableHttp2Tls** to one the following:

   - Set to **0** to disable HTTP/2
   - Set to **1** to enable HTTP/2
4. Restart the computer.

Reference: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4032720/how-to-deploy-custom-cipher-suite-ordering-in-windows-server-2016

Comment: Thanks for this. However HTTP/2 would be disabled for all request right??

Comment: Yes, this will disable it for all request. Not ideal, but for me its fine and its working now for iOS 11 units.